# Why does my Qt program crash when it tries to get "current settings"?

Tags: c++, qt

I've based this section of my code on the terminal example. When I update a field in my mainwindow I wasn't to store the generated string in a structure, then when a command is called in my secondary source, I want to use the passed string.

In my main.h I have

```
struct Settings {
        QString Id;
    };Settings settings() const;
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Settings currentSettings;
```

In my main.cpp is the code that set the value of Id

```
void MainWindow::on_comboBox_currentTextChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    QString Data = arg1;
    if (arg1 == "Universal"){
        Data = "xxx";
    }
    else{
        Data = Format_Class::format_3(Data);
    }
    currentSettings.Id = Data;
}

MainWindow::Settings MainWindow::settings() const
{
    return currentSettings;
}
```

this code defiantly works because currentsettings id gets set to the correct value.

in my mode.H I have

```
namespace Ui {
class Mode;
}

class MainWindow;
class Mode : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Mode(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Mode();

private:
    Ui::Mode *ui;
    MainWindow *settings;
};
```

then in my mode.cpp, the page that actually uses the data I have

```
void Mode::on_pushButton_clicked()//ok
{
    MainWindow::Settings p = settings -> settings();
    QString hash = "#";
    QString end = "\r";
    QString identifier = (p.Id);
```

the function get to the

```
MainWindow::Settings p = settings -> settings();
```

at which it develops a fatal error and crashes. In debugging mode when return currentsettings gets called, currentSettings / id is `<not accessible>` this is after this the program crashes.

when the program crashes the error that occurs is

Signal received

The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system

Signal name: SIGSEGV
Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

Comment: See [What is a segmantation fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-segmentation-fault). Your program crashes exactly on a line where you dereference a pointer : make sure you properly initialize that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Mode, you have:

```
void Mode::on_pushButton_clicked()//ok
{
    MainWindow::Settings p = settings -> settings();
```

Are you sure you initialize Mode's `settings` variable ? It also seems odd to name this variable `settings` when you have specified its type as `MainWindow*`.